# webpack dev server not running

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm creating a webpack config. I've installed the devserver module, and have configured it to run on port 9000 while webpack watches for file changes.

Currently when I run `npx webpack`, the command prompt doesn't return, so I assume that webpack is watching. However, if I visit `http://localhost:9000`, my browser basically shrugs at me. "This site can't be reached"

If I check for activity on the port using:

```
netstat -tunlp | grep 9000
```

... nothing gets returned. Nothing is listening on that port number.

This is my config:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require ('path');

module.exports = {

    mode : 'development',
    
    entry: './src/index.js',

    watch: true,

    output : {
    filename : 'main.js',
    path :         path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true
    },

    devtool : 'inline-source-map',

    devServer : {
    static : './dist',
    logging : 'info',
    overlay :  true,
    port : 9000
    },
    
    plugins: [

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title : 'Development'
    })
    
    ]
    
};
```

Comment: webpack version?

Comment: According to the output of 'npx webpack' when used with my config (pasted above):  webpack 5.65.0

Comment: If you want to run webpack in development, there is 3 options to watch the changes of files. https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#choosing-a-development-tool I personally recommend `webpack-dev-server`

Comment: What you are doing is just build files in a `dist` folder when you run `npx webpack`. There is no server is running in your machine.

Comment: @ikhvjs if there isn't a dev server running, then please let me know why. I have installed the dev server module, and have given it instruction in the pasted config.

Comment: please show us your `package.json` file. If you installed `webpack-dev-server`, you can use `webpack serve` to run it.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue today, very frustrating. I was trying to start webpack dev sever with a similar config file. And it wasn't working.

I had to change the start command to make it work and get rid of `watch: true` in the config file.

```
in the package.json file

  "scripts": {
    NOT WORKING:
    "start": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js",
    
    WORKING:
    "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js",
  }
```

Cheers,